# Comments disappearing for no reason

Tags: support, comments

I just posted my first question on a stackexchange website, someone wrote some comments, and I replied. However, after a few minutes, some of that person's comments disappeared. Why did that happen?

Moreover, after in total we wrote about 10 comments, there was a link that popped up which said something like "Do you want to automatically continue this on the chat page?" I clicked it, but nothing seemed to happen. What exactly was that supposed to do?

Comment: They may have deleted their comments. Comments are by nature not permanent. And that button is supposed to create a chat room, but I think you may not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Jeff Atwood wrote that comments are second-class citizens, CASCC. They can be right, wrong, inconsistent, out-of-date, helpful, unhelpful, polite, rude, shocking,  or no longer pertinent. The poster or a moderator can delete them and explanations are not necessary.

Comment: I'll usually delete my comments here if they become irrelevant, and I know many posters do the same. I'll especially do this if I post a quick comment pointing out a mistake or correction; once the change is made to the answer, assuming I see it, I'll go back and delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not meant for eternity. You can find numerous quotes of that type all across meta.SE and the help centre. Deleting comments is a very simple and easy process both for those who wrote them and mods.

In fact, it is *strongly encouraged* to delete comments once they have served their purpose. And if they are deleted, there is no big note about it, they just disappear. It is also encouraged to flag obsolete comments as being obsolete once they are (e.g. pointing out a typo which has been fixed).

That part explains the disappearing comments. What about the chat bit? Well, extended discussions should be happening in the chat (which doesn’t always happen). I only used that button once or twice and it worked for me. Why it didn’t for you … well, your guess is as good as mine …